# How can i display in listView a Card with only the parking icone?

Tags: flutter

I want to display just the Card with the parking icone in listView, i don't know how can i do it?
any solution guys, the icone depend of `Statucode` .

full code:

```
 Container(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount:
                  superheros_length == null ? 0 : superheros_length.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  

                    int Statucode =
                    jsonDecode(data)['DeviceList'][index]['Statucode'];
                    var vrStatucode = Statucode;

           

                    //algorithme for add icons status (start, move and parking)
                    if (vrStatucode == 61714) {
                      image1 = false;
                      image2 = false;
                      image3 = true;
                    } else if (vrStatucode >= 62465 && vrStatucode < 62466) {
                      image1 = false;
                      image3 = false;
                      image2 = true;
                    } else if (vrStatucode >= 61472) {
                      image1 = true;
                      image3 = false;
                      image2 = false;
                    }

                  

                   
                    return InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          //   vId = jsonDecode(data)['DeviceList'][index]['Device'];
                          // Provider.of<APIProvider>(context, listen: false).setVId(vId);
                          Provider.of<APIProvider>(context, listen: false)
                              .setVId(jsonDecode(data)['DeviceList'][index]
                          ['Device']);
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => Maps(
                                  title: jsonDecode(data)['DeviceList']
                                  [index]['Device_desc'],
                                )),
                          );
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          width: 200,
                          height: 120,

                          child: Card(
                            child: Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Expanded(
                                    flex: 1,
                                    child: Container(
                                        child: Column(
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                            //Center Column contents vertically,
                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              Row(
                                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                                //Center Row contents horizontally,
                                                crossAxisAlignment:
                                                CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                                children: [
                                                  Expanded(
                                                    child: Column(
                                                      children: <Widget>[
                                                        getImage(),
                                                        /*Image.asset(
                                              'assets/images/1617630363130_Voiture 1.png',
                                            ),*/

                                                        Visibility(
                                                          visible: image1,
                                                          child: Row(
                                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                            MainAxisAlignment
                                                                .center,
                                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                                            CrossAxisAlignment
                                                                .center,
                                                            children: [
                                                              Image.asset(
                                                                'assets/images/parking.png',
                                                              ),
                                                            ],
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                        Visibility(
                                                          visible: image2,
                                                          child: Row(
                                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                            MainAxisAlignment
                                                                .center,
                                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                                            CrossAxisAlignment
                                                                .center,
                                                            children: [
                                                              Image.asset(
                                                                'assets/images/starting.png',
                                                              ),
                                                            ],
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                        Visibility(
                                                          visible: image3,
                                                          child: Row(
                                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                            MainAxisAlignment
                                                                .center,
                                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                                            CrossAxisAlignment
                                                                .center,
                                                            children: [
                                                              Image.asset(
                                                                'assets/images/driving.png',
                                                              ),
                                                            ],
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              )
                                            ])),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                      flex: 5,
                                      child: Container(
                                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                        height: 160,
                                        child: Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            Container(
                                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                    top: 10, bottom: 10),
                                                child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                                                  SizedBox(width: 5),
                                                  Expanded(
                                                      child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                                                        Text(
                                                          jsonDecode(data)['DeviceList']
                                                          [index]['Device_desc'],
                                                          overflow:
                                                          TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                            fontSize: 12.0,
                                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                            color: Colors.blueAccent,
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ])),
                                                  Expanded(
                                                      child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                                                        SizedBox(width: 60),
                                                        Text(
                                                          TimeInstant,
                                                          overflow:
                                                          TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                          textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                            fontSize: 12,
                                                            color: Colors.blueGrey,
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ]))
                                                ])),
                                            Row(children: <Widget>[
                                              SizedBox(width: 5),
                                              Expanded(
                                                  child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                                                    Image.asset(
                                                        'assets/images/clock.png',
                                                        height: 12,
                                                        width: 12),
                                                    SizedBox(width: 5),
                                                    Text(
                                                      tTime,
                                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 12,
                                                        color: Colors.blueGrey,
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ])),
                                              Expanded(
                                                  child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                                                    Image.asset(
                                                        'assets/images/calendar.png',
                                                        height: 12,
                                                        width: 12),
                                                    SizedBox(width: 5),
                                                    Text(
                                                      tDate,
                                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 12,
                                                        color: Colors.blueGrey,
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ])),
                                              Expanded(
                                                  child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                                                    Image.asset(
                                                        'assets/images/speed.png',
                                                        height: 12,
                                                        width: 12),
                                                    SizedBox(width: 5),
                                                    Text(
                                                      vrSpeed + " " + "Km/h",
                                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 12,
                                                        color: Colors.blueGrey,
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ]))
                                            ]),

                                            SizedBox(height: 15),
                                            Row(children: <Widget>[
                                              SizedBox(width: 5),
                                              Expanded(
                                                  child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                                                    Image.asset(
                                                        'assets/images/map-pin.png',
                                                        height: 12,
                                                        width: 12),
                                                    SizedBox(width: 5),
                                                    Text(
                                                      jsonDecode(data)['DeviceList']
                                                      [index]['Adresse'],
                                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 9,
                                                        color: Colors.blueGrey,
                                                      ),
                                                      maxLines: 2,
                                                    ),
                                                  ])),
                                            ])
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ))
                                ]),
                          ),
                        ));
                  },
                ),
              ),
```

Screen
[image]

Answer (score 0):

just delete the getImage() methode if you don't need it. By Visibilty the icon is diplayed depending on the status code.

Comment: no,  getImage() methode for display the car's images

Comment: In your code you call a getImage() Methode straight above your comment "/*Image.asset('assets/images/1617630363130_Voiture 1.png',),*/" which seams to load the unwanted image of the cars